# How can I call variadic template constructor in c++?

Tags: c++, templates

I am learning c++ template technique.

I made a constructor with variadic template augments like following.

The class is simplified very much, so it does not have meaning. 
However I could not call the function. Compiler tells me that it cannot call constructor directly.

How can I call it?

```
#include <utility>

class TemplateVariadicAugments {
public:

    template <typename FutureInnterTemplateClass, typename... Args>
    TemplateVariadicAugments(Args&&... args) : value_(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    virtual ~TemplateVariadicAugments() = default;

    int value_;
};

void test_variadic_template_augments(void) {

    TemplateVariadicAugments a = TemplateVariadicAugments::template TemplateVariadicAugments<int, int>(1);

}
```

Comment: `TemplateVariadicAugments a {1};`?

Comment: @Danh : Thank you for answering. I tried it but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the form you wrote it, there is no way to call the constructor. First, in C++ you cannot call a constructor by it's name, even in trivial cases:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() {}
};

void foo()
{
    A::A(); // Illegal.
}
```

Then, as you can't call the constructor directly, you can't instantiate the template explicitly, so all template arguments must be deduced. But in your case `FutureInnterTemplateClass` cannot be deduced, as it's not used anywhere in the constructor.

The solution is to remove redundant argument from the constructor:

```
template <typename... Args>
TemplateVariadicAugments(Args&&... args) : value_(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
```

Now an object may be constructed as follows:

```
TemplateVariadicAugments obj(1);
```

and `Args` in this case wil lbe correctly deduced to `int`.

But in this case it's unclear what did you want to say with variadic template argument, as if you construct an object like this:

```
TemplateVariadicAugments obj(1, 2);
```

your `value_` member initialization will become equivalent ti this code:

```
int value_(1, 2);
```

which is obviously ill-formed.